# PHP Cookie changing a variable

Tags: php, variables, cookies, setcookie

on my server I'm unable to get a cookie to work as intended. Here's my code:

```
$id = '1';
if(! isset($_COOKIE["Count"])){
setcookie("Count", "1", time()+3600);
}

if($_COOKIE["Count"] > 2){
$id = '0';
exit();
}
else {
setcookie("Count", ($_COOKIE["Count"] + 1), time()+3600);
}
```

The cookie **Count** is intended to increase in value each time a visitor accesses the page. 3 or more times sets variable **id** to a certain value, otherwise set to 1. Echoing the variable displays 1 from the set number of requests, though after which becomes null. Echoing the cookie's value also does not respond, despite being detected.

I believe my error is the way in which I change the value. I'm not sure how to properly set it.

Any help's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = '1';
if(! isset($_COOKIE["Count"])){
setcookie("Count", "1", time()+3600);
}

if($_COOKIE["Count"] > 2){
$id = '0';
exit();
}
else {
$newcount = $_COOKIE["Count"]++;
setcookie("Count", $newcount, time()+3600);
}
```

calculating and calling the global inside a function like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    setcookie("Count", ((int)$_COOKIE["Count"] + 1), time()+3600);

Remember, when you set a Cookie, you can´t see the new value on it until the next request.

Answer (score 0):

$_COOKIE is not the proper way. Use [filter_input()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-input.php) function instead

Comment: $_COOKIE isn't deprecated. You're thinking of $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS.

Comment: filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, "nameOfTheCookie") works fine

According to [The documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) HTTP_COOKIE_VARS is deprecated yes

I edited my message, deprecated wasn't appropriate.

Comment: I'm also interested in why using $_COOKIE isn't the "proper way."

Comment: Cookie is accessible from users and may be changed by them. Use cookies without verifications can make security breach. Depends what you store on it.